# Wordpress – Loading different CSS for different page not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using the following fork to apply a different css style to a page (ID 130).

```
function wipkip_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'wipkip-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  if ( is_page(130) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wipkip-style-home', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/style-homepage.css' );
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that it generates a faulty URL and I'm not sure why. This is the URL it generates:

```
http://myurl.com/wp/wp-content/themes/wipkip/style.css/style-homepage.css?ver=5.2.2
```

It somehow automatically adds **/style-homepage.css** after the already existing **style.css**

Anyone know a fix for this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_stylesheet_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri) - retrieves the URI of the current theme stylesheet.

Use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) to retrieve stylesheet directory URI and then append style-homepage.css.